# Inverse of Gaussian Kernel Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

Let a gaussian kernel be defined as $K(x_i, x_j) \equiv \exp(-\alpha |x_i-x_j|^2)+\beta \delta_{ij}$, and define the kernel matrix of some set of datapoints $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ as the $n\times n$ matrix $K$ with $K_{ij} = K(x_i, x_j)$.

This is a common construction in various fields, e.g. Gaussian Processes. Is there a fast way of calculating the inverse of the kernel matrix?

---

Thoughts: if we could break down the matrix $K$ into the form $\beta I + u u^T$ for some column vector $u$, we could use the Sherman–Morrison formula to quickly calculate the inverse, however, we know such a $u$ would be infinite dimensional. Is there another trick one could use?

Comment: Were you able to make any progress in this problem. I was also additionally interested in the properties of this matrix apart from positive semi-definitiness.

Comment: @dineshdileep - No, but thinking about it some more, it's unlikely this has a nice solution, otherwise I'd expect to find it in one of the many texts on GP's.

Comment: This source covers some approximation methods for the inverse: http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW8.pdf. I have also run into the same problem, albeit from a computational standpoint: inverting the Kernel matrix for a large number of datapoints yields memory errors as the computation exceeds the amount of RAM I have on hand.

Comment: @Sentient - I'll accept that as an answer if you can add a bit more detail about the contents in that link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much works has been done on the scalability of Gaussian Processes. The main idea is to approximate your kernel matrix $K$ with another matrix that admits faster operations.  This allows us to have fast matrix vector multiplications when optimizing hyper-parameters and use iterative algorithms such as Conjugate Gradients or GMRES to invert $K$.

The Structured Kernel Interpolation(SKI) paper gives a method for approximating your data with data on a grid, which allows you to use inducing point methods, toeplitz, kronecker methods to get the fast computations. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.01057