# How to derive an inverse of Gaussian Kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

As an example, say I have a 2D function (Gaussian process kernel):
$$K(x_i, x_j) \equiv \exp(-\alpha |x_i-x_j|^2)+\beta \delta_{ij}$$
Is there a way to analytically express $K^{-1}(x_i,x_j)$, s.t. matrices $K$ and $K^{-1}$ made from $K(x_i,x_j)$ and $K^{-1}(x_i,x_j)$ are inverses of each other? An approximation would also be great.

A similar question has been asked before [(link)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2819097/inverse-of-gaussian-kernel-matrix), but I think that is for numerical calculation of $K^{-1}$. I am seeking an analytic expression or formula for $K^{-1}(x_i,x_j)$.

Comment: You know how to invert a $2\times 2$ matrix, right?

Comment: Yes, but here the matrix size can be infinitely large.

Comment: So, why do you write "2D"? And "infinitely large" makes no sense. You mean it has arbitrary size.

Comment: The function is 2D, as in it takes in two variables $x_i$ and $x_j$, and outputs a scalar. I did not say the matrix is 2D. The rows vary $x_i$ and columns vary $x_j$. Since the continuous function exists in an infinite-dimensional space, the matrix size is infinite. Gaussian process kernel by definition defines covariances between infinitely many random variables.

Comment: You really have to learn to express yourself in an understandable way. First, 2D means two-dimensional. But as far as I understand, nothing is two-dimensional here. Furthermore: "the continuous function" which continuous function? "in an infinite-dimensional space" Which infinite-dimensional space? The matrix size is infinite if you have infinitely many $x_k$.

Comment: This post assumes the readers are familiar with the concept of the Gaussian Process kernel, where the terminologies that I used here are commonly used.

Comment: It's indeed true that I'm not an expert in Gaussian kernels. However, you should try to make people understand better what you're talking about. Then you get more answers. For example, you haven't answered my two questions. Can you?

Comment: Thanks for showing interest in this post. It is common to call a function that takes in two variables and outputs a scalar ($R^2 \rightarrow R$), a (continuous) 2D function since there are '2' variables. When people say a function lives in an infinite-dimensional space, they are thinking the function as a vector, wherein each index we have a value for $f(x_i)$ (showing $R \rightarrow R$ function here as an example) and index $i$ ranges from $0$ to $N$ (some integer) and $x_i$ increases with $i$. To truly express the continuous function in the vector form, we need to $N\rightarrow \infty$.